# how to set collision between nodes and other svg element in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

In my example, I want to set all the circle not only collide with each other, but also collide with the arc, how could I do that , any help is appreciated.

[code here](https://jsfiddle.net/kanesyang/otenqpzu/)

```
    var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
        .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(5))
        .force('x', d3.forceX().x((d) => {
            return centerGroup[topicArrayList.indexOf(d.topic)][0] * 0.9
        }))
        .force('y', d3.forceY().y((d) => {
            return centerGroup[topicArrayList.indexOf(d.topic)][1] * 0.9
        }))
        .force('collision', d3.forceCollide().radius((d) => {
            return d.radius;
        }))
        .on('tick', ticked);

    function ticked() {
        var u = d3.select('svg g')
            .selectAll('circle')
            .data(nodes);

        u.enter()
            .append('circle')
            .attr('r', function(d) {
                return d.radius;
            })
            .merge(u)
            .attr('cx', function(d) {
                return d.x;
            })
            .attr('cy', function(d) {
                return d.y;
            })

        u.exit().remove();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the trick suggested by [Mike Bostock's Bounded Force Layout](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1129492): when updating the position of nodes in `.ticked()`, add a check to make sure you're not placing something outside the boundary. However, there's a bit of math to do in order to make your boundary an arc with thickness rather than a rectangle with no thickness.